# sYSMALLOc assertion failed when using "new" keyword

Tags: c++, gdb, new-operator, valgrind

> **EDIT:** For clarity's sake, I'll leave the question as it is. The
>   problem seems to be that the `Kameleon` class uses `boost`, and since
>   my own code also uses it there are probably conflicting versions and
>   that's where the problems come from.

**Original question:**

Lot's of info, but I have tried to boil it down to the interesting parts. I am writing an application that uses instances of a class `Kameleon` (that I did not write myself) to do various tasks. When I try to use the `new` keyword to allocate an instance, I run into trouble. Here is a minified version of the problem:

```
#include <ccmc/Kameleon.h>

int main() {
  ccmc::Kameleon k;
  ccmc::Kameleon *k2 = new ccmc::Kameleon(); // <-- crashes with this line
  delete k2:
  return 0;
 }
```

SIDE NOTE: Commenting out the `new` allocation of `k2` and only running `ccmc::Kameleon k` works, and I can use the variable. However, the program segfaults when main() returns when I try that. The destructor does nothing.

The `Kameleon constructor does the following:

```
// Kameleon.cpp
/*47*/ Kameleon::Kameleon() : model(NULL), // model is a non-const pointer 
/*48*/                        modelName("NA"), // modelName is a non-const std::string
/*49*/                        missingValue(0.f) // missingValue is a non-const float
/*50*/ {}
```

I have tried my problems with error messages, gdb and valgrind but can't seem to find the source. This is what running the program gives me:

```
FurnaceApp: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

gdb tells me the following:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6b1c425 in __GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00007ffff6b1fb8b in __GI_abort () at abort.c:91
#2  0x00007ffff6b6415d in __malloc_assert (assertion=<optimized out>, file=<optimized out>, line=<optimized out>, function=<optimized out>)
    at malloc.c:300
#3  0x00007ffff6b67664 in sYSMALLOc (av=0x7ffff6e9e720, nb=48) at malloc.c:2448
#4  _int_malloc (av=0x7ffff6e9e720, bytes=27) at malloc.c:3892
#5  0x00007ffff6b68fb5 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=27) at malloc.c:2924
#6  0x00007ffff746cded in operator new(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007ffff7455a89 in std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007ffff7457495 in char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007ffff74575e3 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x00007ffff7757caf in ccmc::Kameleon::Kameleon (this=0x67d920) at Kameleon.cpp:49
#11 0x0000000000415516 in main ()
```

Then finally, valgrind gives me a lot of output but this section looks most like the previous errors:

```
==11789== Invalid write of size 8
==11789==    at 0x52ECC8D: ccmc::Kameleon::Kameleon() (buckets.hpp:128)
==11789==    by 0x415515: main (in /home/vsand/OpenSpace/Furnace/FurnaceApp)
==11789==  Address 0x6683a00 is 0 bytes after a block of size 464 alloc'd
==11789==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11789==    by 0x41550A: main (in /home/vsand/OpenSpace/Furnace/FurnaceApp)
==11789== 
==11789== Invalid write of size 8
==11789==    at 0x52ECC94: ccmc::Kameleon::Kameleon() (table.hpp:226)
==11789==    by 0x415515: main (in /home/vsand/OpenSpace/Furnace/FurnaceApp)
==11789==  Address 0x6683a28 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==11789== 
==11789== Invalid write of size 8
==11789==    at 0x52ECC9F: ccmc::Kameleon::Kameleon() (Kameleon.cpp:49)
==11789==    by 0x415515: main (in /home/vsand/OpenSpace/Furnace/FurnaceApp)
==11789==  Address 0x6683a30 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==11789==
```

Looking around here and there it seems like these errors usually comes up when using `malloc` improperly and writing beyond allocated memory etc. There is a lot of code in the `Kameleon` classes, but since I did not write it myself I have problems trying to track it down. Any bug hunting tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the bug is in `// Other initializations`

Comment: @john: I removed unnecessary parts from the code and updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
==11789== Invalid write of size 8
==11789==    at 0x52ECC8D: ccmc::Kameleon::Kameleon() (buckets.hpp:128)
==11789==    by 0x415515: main (in /home/vsand/OpenSpace/Furnace/FurnaceApp)
==11789==  Address 0x6683a00 is 0 bytes after a block of size 464 alloc'd
==11789==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11789==    by 0x41550A: main (in /home/vsand/OpenSpace/Furnace/FurnaceApp)
```

This means that:

- your code that allocates an instance of `ccmc::Kameleon` thinks that the `sizeof(ccmc::Kameleon)` is 464, while
- your code that actually implements the `ccmc::Kameleon::Kameleon()` writes to bytes `[this+464, this+472)`.

The most likely cause:

- you have changed the definition of the class in `buckets.hpp`, and
- you have not recompiled *all* code that uses it, thus violating the [one definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

You *must* rebuild *all* the code which uses `Kameleon`, and once you do, your problems will go away.

> buckets.hpp is from boost headers

Another possibility is that you are linking with a library that was compiled against a different version of Boost. That *can't* work, you *have* to use exact same version of Boost.

The final possibility is that Boost is compiled with an inconsistent set of `-DXX` flags, resulting in different definitions of the `Kameleon` class (and again violating the one definition rule).

Comment: Thanks, I'm on it. Seems like both buckets.hpp and table.hpp (and more files with error like them) are from the boost headers.

Comment: Saw your update about boost just after commenting on it myself. After more digging, it seems like Kameleon does use boost and that is probably where the trouble comes from. I'll accept this answer and try to solve the boost conflict!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
Kameleon::Kameleon(): model(NULL), modelName("N/A") {
    // ...
}
```

Is `modelName` const by any chance?

Can you also remove all uncesseray code in the constructor of `CDFReader` to isolate the bug? Or even better:

```
#include "Kameleon.h" // or whatever

int main(){
    ccmc::Kameleon k;
    ccmc::Kameleon *k2 = new ccmc::Kameleon();
    delete k2;
}
```

Is `Kameleon` a derived class? Does it overload the `new` operator?

Comment: Thanks, I overhauled the question and modified the constructor. It still crashes, but with slightly different error messages!

Comment: @VictorSand: Which call fails? both? try commenting the second one. Does this class overload the `new` operator?

Comment: When just running `ccmc::Kameleon k' I don't get the same errors. I can use the variable right after creating it. However, when main() returns, I get a segfault that I can't trace. I checked the Kameleon destructor, nothing seems weird there. Could that be related to the problems when using new?

Comment: It is not derived, it does not overload the new operator.

Comment: Hold on, now you say the error is during program termination? That is not the same problem at all. Can you create the object successfully in both cases?

Comment: The program termination error occurs when just creating k. I can then use the object. When allocating k2, the original problem occurs and the program crashes as soon as I try to allocate it.

Comment: I don't think there is much we can do without the class definition. Try to have a look at `Kameleon` in detail, look both header and source code, look for class re-definition or weird constructs